# java duplicate key in same json object

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to parse a JSON response using jsonObject library in Java, but receiving exception with duplicated key. I need to parse this JSON as it is, without any loop and without any conversion. Some solution stated that I have to convert those values to array, so I need your suggestion. Is there any library that can parse my json which has duplicated key without any change?
This is my code :

```java
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));  //stream to resource
    
String inputLine;
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
    
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    res.append(inputLine);
}
    
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(res.toString());
```

my error response :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Duplicate key "Account"
    at org.json.JSONObject.putOnce(JSONObject.java:1121)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:208)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:208)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
```

Comment: edit your question: add your response sample data(the link you have added is not correct, ), state your problem clearly and your object, the way you tried all relevant things. Hope, you will get help

Comment: Duplicate keys within the same object are not [valid JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (which describes objects as "unordered **sets** of name/value pairs").

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of net.sf.json.JSONObject. It will accept JSON with the duplicate key.

This library will retain the duplicated values by storing them into arrays. If multiple same keys are available it will create one key with all the values as Array.

And also the coding part is just a single line. Once you parsed the json using net.sf.json.JSONObject then you can supply this to jackson library.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject( "{ \"a\": \"a\", \"a\": { \"b\": {},\"b\": true}}" );

System.out.println( "net.sf.json.JSONObject: " + jsonObject );

JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree( jsonObject.toString() );

System.out.println( "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode" + jsonNode );
```

Output:

```
net.sf.json.JSONObject: {"a":["a",{"b":[{},true]}]}

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode{"a":["a",{"b":[{},true]}]}
```

Maven dependency of net.sf.json

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm getting "Could not resolve dependencies for project ... Failure to find net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.4" when trying to mvn install with the above net.sf.json-lib dependency